# How to add class to li based on a in nested menu?

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to add class to li based on actual link in nested menu in Jquery ? Thank you.

HTML:

```
<ul>
  <li>
   <a></a>
   <ul>
    <li><a></a></li>
   </ul>
  <li>
</ul>
```

Jquery:

```
var prev_url = document.referrer;
var $current = $('.arrows_list1-1 li a[href="' + prev_url + '"]');
(don't know).addClass('current-menu-item');
```

Comment: can put your html as well?

Comment: can you do this `$('.arrows_list1-1 li a[href="' + prev_url + '"]').addClas('current-menu-item')`?

Comment: I need to add this class to li not a ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is 'li' element of the selected 'a' you want to add class to? if so, try

```
$current.closest('li').addClass('current-menu-item')
```

Alternatively, it can be done this way:

```
$('.arrows_list1-1 li').filter(function(){ 
    return $(this).has('a[href="'+ document.referrer + '"]').length > 0;  
}).addClass('current-menu-item');
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be safer to use a `.filter` method:

```
var $current = $('.arrows_list1-1 li a').filter(function() {
    return this.href === document.referrer;
});

$current.addClass('current-menu-item');
```

the rationale being that the `href` attribute may be in any format (absolute, relative, etc) but the `href` *property* is always normalised to being an absolute URL.